# Terminal prints a "?" character on x86 subtraction operation

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, i386

Putting together some x86 assembly for just a simple subtraction problem to learn and I'm running into an issue. Below is my code that I've tried so far:

```
section .text
    global _start


_start:
    MOV EAX, 4          ; sys_write call
    MOV EBX, 1          ; file descriptor
    MOV ECX, dispMsg
    MOV EDX, dispMsgLen
    INT 0x80            ; execute instruction set

    MOV EAX, 3          ; sys_read call
    MOV EBX, 2
    MOV [tempf], ECX    ; move user-input to tempf
    MOV EDX, 3
    INT 0x80

    MOV EAX, [tempf]    ; move tempf to EAX
    SUB EAX, '0'        ; convert EAX to decimal

    MOV EBX, 32         ; move value 32 to EBX
    SUB EBX, '0'        ; convert EBX to decimal

    SUB EAX, EBX        ; sub EAX to EBX
    ADD EAX, '0'        ; convert EAX to ascii

    MOV [res], EAX      ; move EAX to res

    MOV EAX, 4
    MOV EBX, 1
    MOV ECX, [res]
    MOV EDX, 3
    INT 0x80

    MOV EAX, 1          ; sys_exit call
    MOV EBX, 1
    INT 0x80


section .bss
    tempf resb 3
    res resb 3


section .data
    dispMsg db 'Input a value', 0xa
    dispMsgLen equ $-dispMsg
```

Upon compiling and running, the user is prompted to input a number. When they hit enter, I'm expecting the code to subtract the user's input by 32 and print the result out to the console. However, I've only been getting a "?" character in a diamond in the console when the user inputs a number and presses enter. I've read that this could be because there is nothing in the [res] variable to be printed, but I'm sure I've stored the difference between `user input - 32` in the res variable.

Any help is appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: Maybe you haven't understood the difference between ASCII code for digit characters, vs. integer values.  `mov ebx, 32` sets EBX = 32 = 0x20 = 0b10000.  In the CPU itself, it's stored as binary bits.  Subtracting `'0'` (the number 48 decimal, aka 0x30 hex) leaves EBX = 32 - 48 = -16.  So you're subtracting that from the ASCII code for the first byte of whatever you typed.  Use a debugger to look at the low byte of EAX (AL) that you store into `res`.

Comment: BTW, you're reading input from fd=2 (stderr), which is weird.  That happens to work in a normal terminal because all 3 standard file descriptors (0, 1, and 2) are duplicates of the same read-write file description open on the tty, when you run a program from a bash shell.

Answer (score 4):

So, your `read` system call and its aftermath don't make much sense.

```
    MOV EAX, 3          ; sys_read call
    MOV EBX, 2
```

Why are you trying to read from file descriptor 2?  That's standard error and it's not necessarily expected to be open for reading.  If you want to get input from the user, read from standard input, file descriptor 0.

```
    MOV [tempf], ECX    ; move user-input to tempf
```

That's not what this does; it takes the (garbage) value that's in `ECX` (which incidentally is four bytes) and stores it at address `tempf` (which incidentally is only three bytes).  I think you meant to write `MOV ECX, tempf`.  Note the absence of brackets because we want the *address* of `tempf` to be in ECX, not the value located at that address in memory.

```
    MOV EDX, 3
```

Okay, so you're going to read three bytes.  I'm not quite sure why three, but...

```
    INT 0x80

    MOV EAX, [tempf]    ; move tempf to EAX
```

... this loads *four* bytes, since `EAX` is a 32-bit register.

If you just want a single digit from the user (which is all your code seems capable of processing), then you should probably:

- just read one byte
- load one byte into an 8-bit register, e.g. `MOV AL, [tempf]`
- Operate on that 8-bit register from then on, e.g. `SUB AL, '0'` and so forth.